"Which of you...is/are"? Which form should the verb take?
"Which is free?" is correct, but;

Which of you are free right now?

Which of you is free right now?


"Does anyone know?" is correct, but;

Does any of you know?

Do any of you know?


Those two options seem a bit too complicated for me to figure out by myself because of "you" being part of the subject phrase. Can someone point a way? Thank you.

Regarding the second query: I think that "does any of you know", "does any least one of you know" and "does anyone know" are synonymous with one another.
